# Missing Word Object Library 15.0

Tags: excel, vba

I created a xlsm document that embeds and modifys doc files. I did this on my pc with word 2016.

I have to use this file at work where we only have excel 2013, and Word Object Library 15.0 is missing. The version installed is 11.0

How do i solve this compatibility issue?
I'd prefer to make the xlsm on my pc directly woth the 11.0

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use late binding instead of early binding.

Answer (score 1):

The library file is part of a later edition of Word and you don't have distribution rights to it so you can't copy it to a different machine. You need to use late binding so your code will decide what library to use dynamically. Change your declaration statements to use an Object rather than a specific class.

You have not provided code, but it would look something like this:

```
Dim objWordApp As Object
Set objWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Dim wordDoc As Object
Set wordDoc = objWordApp.XXX  ' Do something with the Word Doc object
```